# Node.JS MySQL logging result to console without being asked to and acting strangely

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I have come across a new very strange error when using Node.JS MySQL. I seem to be logging a result in the console even though there is no line in my code to log it; also when I do log a result it logs a different one from the one that seemingly logs automatically and the one which comes up when I use PHPMyAdmin.

Here is my code (I have put it into its own file to make sure there is no event elsewhere in my other file firing the console.log):

```js
const config = require("./config.json");
const colors = require('colors');
var mysql = require('mysql');

function get_datetime() {
    let date_ob = new Date();

    // current date
    // adjust 0 before single digit date
    let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);

    // current month
    let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    // current year
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();

    // current hours
    let hours = date_ob.getHours();

    // current minutes
    let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();

    // current seconds
    let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();

    // prints date & time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
    var dateTimeOfMessage = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    return dateTimeOfMessage;
}

var currentdate = get_datetime();
// Check for expired users by taking current date from database for all users where date is within a reasonable range. (e.g. WHERE date = 2 days lower than get_datetime().)
// Remove users who have had the role for over 2 days unless they bought it.

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.database.host,
    user: config.database.user,
    password: config.database.password,
    database: config.database.name
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var sql = "SELECT userID FROM premium_trials WHERE DATEDIFF('" + currentdate + "', datereceived) >= 2 AND boughtPremium = 0;";
    console.log(sql);
    con.query(sql, function(result, err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        con.end();

        if (result == null || result == "") {

            console.log("null value".yellow);
            console.log(result + "        ---        Result log on line 53");

        } else {
            console.log("Still working".green);
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                console.log(result[i].userID);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

[image: Image of console output]

Here is the text version of my console output:

```
SELECT userID FROM premium_trials WHERE DATEDIFF('2020-09-07 22:25:43', datereceived) >= 2 AND boughtPremium = 0;
[ RowDataPacket { userID: '216324181783085056' } ]
null value
null        ---        Result log on line 53
```

I have also attached an image of the PHPMyAdmin output, showing it is correct.

[image: PHPMyAdmin output]

Comment: What is `"null value".yellow` ?

Comment: It just makes the text appear yellow in colour in the console, as seen in the screenshot. It comes from the colors module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inverted `err` and `result`. With callbacks, the error is generally the first argument of the callback and the results the others arguments.

You can see it in [the example here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction).

So

```
con.query(sql, function(result, err) {
```

Should be

```
con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
```